# 16x2 LCD Interfacing with Arduino Uno

Tags: android, arduino-uno

I connected Arduino with 16x2 LCD with the following connection
[image]

The program I used

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

// initialize the library with the numbers of the interface pins
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

void setup() {
  // set up the LCD's number of columns and rows: 
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  // Print a message to the LCD.
  lcd.print("hello, world!");
}

void loop() {
  // set the cursor to column 0, line 1
  // (note: line 1 is the second row, since counting begins with 0):
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  // print the number of seconds since reset:
  lcd.print(millis()/1000);
}
```

When I connect my Arduino to LCD and upload the program to Arduino, the display works and shows appropriate output.

Now, when I disconnect the Arduino from USB cable(turn off power supply) and reconnected it back(connect it to a power source), the screen only shows BLACK BOXES on the top line.

I tried reconnecting Arduino to power supply but it does not work. I also tried resetting Arduino board but it does not work.

I programmed Arduino for many times but it works only once and stop showing result when I disconnect power...

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced my ATMEGA328P-PU on Arduino chip with a new one. And Now it works!

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the screen at the beginning of your code lcd.clear should wh